# setting CSS in seperate style class not reflected in UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material UI in my React component. But the styles I'm giving in a seperate style.css is not reflected in screen. I'm using this https://material-ui.com/components/radio-buttons/.

I need to change the margin, width and so many for that radio group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import your own custom css into the component :

```
import './custom.css'
```

And make sure you use the ***!important*** tag after your styles if you want to overwrite the main styles :

```
.classname {
  margin-left : 10px !important ;
}
```

**Note**

To find the classname of the element you want to edit you need to go to your browser's devtools and inspect the element and see what classnames it has so you should have the same classname in your css with custom styles to overwrite it .